# Updating Values on Main Page - Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Hows it going guys. I have been looking for two days now and I cant seem to connect the dots. Please forgive me I am somewhat experienced with python but OOP concepts are still a little unclear. I have seen a couple similar posts but the python is a little over my head.

What I am trying to do is set the temperature (and eventually humidity) in a separate screen (Button called Set Temp). Then have that set temp value from that screen show up on my main screen. I tried to tie the temperature value to a global variable (**tep**). Then when one would hit main menu button (within the set temp screen) and call a method within the main screen class that would reference that global **tep** variable. But when I do this nothing happens. I have tired to call it by ID, create a method within the main menu to explicitly update that variable but to no avail and vice versa but nothing seems to work. I tried looking how to refresh the screen but the examples were over my head. If someone could shed some light on this issue that would be awesome.

Thanks for taking the time to read my post!

python file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from random import randint
from kivy.lang import Builder  
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Window.size = (600,250)

tep = 75
# Window Manager Class
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

# Main home menu Class
class MyTerrLayout(Screen):
    internal_read = ObjectProperty(None)
    external_read = ObjectProperty(None)
    target_temp = ObjectProperty(None)
    target_hum = ObjectProperty(None)

    def set_temp(self):
        global tep
        self.ids._Target_Temp.text = str(tep)
        print(str(tep))

# Temprature Screen Class / Window  
class TempWindow(Screen):
    temp_menu = ObjectProperty(None)
    def sub_temp(self):
        global tep
        tep = tep - 1
        self.temp_menu.text = str(tep)

    def add_temp(self):
        global tep
        tep = tep + 1
        self.temp_menu.text = str(tep)
    def set_temp(self):
        MyTerrLayout().set_temp()

# Humidity Class / Window
class HumWindow(Screen):   
    pass


# Builder Section
kv = Builder.load_file('terrlayoutV1.kv')

class TerrLayout(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__=="__main__":
    TerrLayout().run()
```

Kivy File

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
WindowManager:
    MyTerrLayout:
    TempWindow:
    HumWindow:

<MyTerrLayout>:
    name: "main"
    internal_read: internal_reading
    external_read: external_reading
    target_temp: _Target_Temp
    target_hum: _Target_Hum

    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        RelativeLayout:
            Label:
                id: _internal
                text: 'Internal Temp/Humidity'
                size_hint: 0.5 , .166
                pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'top': 1}
            Label:
                text: 'Target:'
                font_size: 15
                size_hint: 0.125 , .166
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.1, 'top': 0.834}   
            Label:
                id: _Target_Temp
                size_hint: 0.125 , .166
                pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'top': 0.834}
            Label:
                id: _Target_Hum
                size_hint: 0.125 , .166
                pos_hint: {'x': .38, 'top': 0.834}
            Label:
                text: 'Current:'
                size_hint: 0.125 , .166
                pos_hint: {'x': .55, 'top': 0.834}
            Label:
                id: internal_reading
                text: '25C/35%'
                size_hint: 0.125 , .166
                pos_hint: {'x': .75, 'top': 0.834}
            Label:
                id: _external
                text: 'External Temp/Humidity'
                size_hint: 0.5, .166
                pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'top': 0.668}
            Label:
                id: external_reading    
                size_hint: 0.5, .166
                pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'top': 0.502}
            Label:
                id: _heatbed
                text: 'Heatbed Temprature'
                size_hint: 0.5, .166
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.25, 'top': 0.336}
            Label:
                id: heatbed_reading
                text: '80C'
                size_hint: 0.5, .166
                pos_hint: {'x': 0.25, 'top': 0.17}
        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'rl-tb'
            spacing: 1.5
            Button:
                id: _Set_Temp
                text: 'Set Temp'
                size_hint: [.5, .25]
                on_release: app.root.current = "Temp"
            Button:
                id: _Set_Hum
                text: 'Set Humidity'
                size_hint: [.5, .25]
                on_release: app.root.current = "Hum"
            Button:
                id: _Set_Fan
                text: 'Set Fan Time'
                size_hint: [.5, .25]
            Button:
                id: _Set_Light
                text: 'Set Light Time'
                size_hint: [.5, .25]
            Button:
                id: _Tog_Light
                text: 'Toggle Light'
                size_hint: [.5, .25]
            Button:
                id: _Tog_Fan
                text: 'Toggle Fan'
                size_hint: [.5, .25]
            Button:
                id: _Dis_Mode
                text: 'Display Mode'
                size_hint: [1, .25]



<TempWindow>:
    name: "Temp" 
    temp_menu: set_tep_menu
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            id: set_tep_menu
            size_hint: 1, .5
            font_size: 32
        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'rl-tb'
            Button:
                text: "Increase Temp"
                on_press: root.add_temp()
                size_hint: [1, .3]
            Button:
                text: "Decrease Temp"
                on_press: root.sub_temp()
                size_hint: [1, .3]
            Button:
                text: "Main Menu"
                on_release: app.root.current = "main"
                on_release: root.set_temp() #calling method to set temp
                size_hint: [1, .3]

<HumWindow>:
    name: "Hum"
    Button:
        text: "Humidity"
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
def set_temp(self):
    MyTerrLayout().set_temp()
```

is creating a new instance of `MyTerrLayout` and calling `set_temp()` on that instance. However, that new instance of `MyTerrLayout` is not part of your GUI, so no changes are visible. To actually change your GUI, you need to call the `set_temp()` method of the `MyTerrLayout` instance that is in your GUI. To do that, change the `set_temp()` method of `TempWindow` to:

```
def set_temp(self):
    terrLayout = self.manager.get_screen('main')
    terrLayout.set_temp()
```